# Can I provide a better name for a pre-defined class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class that has been pre-defined by an XSD but the name is long and confusing.  I can't rename the class directly.  Is there a way to create a new class with a better name and inherit the poorly named one without having to write a bunch of setters and getters since the XSD could potentially change over time?

I tried just creating an empty class like this:

```
Public Class TaskDetails : Inherits ExternalResponseTaskDetailTaskDetail

End Class
```

And that would work fine, except I get a casting error when I try to

```
Dim td as TaskDetails = ertdtd
```

This seems like I'm asking a very stupid question, but try as I might, I can't get my Google-Fu working for me on it.  The long class name does make sense inside the library I'm working in, but outside the library, it really doesn't.  Especially since the library contains an ExternalRequestTaskDetails class and ExternalRequestTaskDetailsTaskDetails is an element contained within it.

Comment: I don't know the answer but thought you deserved an upvote for one of the best questions I've seen from a new person in a long time.

Comment: Tim, yes, you are correct.  I've fixed that.

Comment: @user3500506 - What is the error you get when you run the code?

Comment: Just create an alias, like `Imports ShortName = ClassLibrary1.AVeryLongAndPainfullyToUseName`

Comment: error is "Value of type 'xsdTest.ExternalResponseTaskDetailTaskDetail' cannot be converted to 'xsdTest.TaskDetails'.      (xsdTest is my Namespace)

Comment: @HansPassant - that would have to be done in the app implementing the library though wouldn't it?  I'm trying to get to a point where outside the library, you don't even need to know that ExternalResponseTaskDetailTaskDetail exists

Comment: You are asking for a pony. Look up "encapsulation" in your favorite OOP book.

Comment: Well.. I'm asking for an Equus Caballus.  I just want to call it a pony.